# PHP cURL get requesting host

Tags: php, apache, curl, get, cgi

I have two PHP based sites http://domain1.tld and http://domain2.tld. From domain1.tld I start a cURL (get) request to domain2.tld.

How can I get the requesting host ("domain1.tld")?
I tried `var_dump($_SERVER)` and `var_dump(apache_request_headers())`but these didn't give me the requesting host.

One more important information: domain2.tld is running in CGI mode.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As you can see above, I tried the `$_SERVER` variable and the `apache_request_headers()` function.

Answer (score 1):

use the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super global on http://domain2.tld

You can try either `$_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"]` for the host name,

and if that doesn't work, the `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` will give you the corresponding IP-address

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working as expected - I'm running my domain on a shared server so the lookup of the name via `gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])` just gives me the domain name of the server (understandably) - not my own one. Is this possible anyhow?

Comment: If you are running on a shared server, you can't guarantee that the service provider would identify with your domain name, therefore I guess that the best solution is to accept request from the shared server's ip and hope that no one else on your shared server would make curl requests :-)

Comment: Of course - I'll compare the IP addresses, if there's no possibility to get the requesting domain.